# Why scss/ complied css not renderd in browser on certain child elements

Tags: html, css, npm, sass

I am using Visual Studio Code editor & running "npm run sass" in bash terminal.

When I make changes to the scss file the terminal shows:

=> changed: C:\Users\kenne\modern_portfolio\scss\main.scss
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Users\kenne\modern_portfolio\dist\css\main.css

In my main.css file the compiled css is added every time I make a change.

When I serve the page in Chrome, FireFox, Edge the changes aren't rendered for some child elements. (.tech, .item-lang)

When I inspect it shows the styles are computed.

The elements that aren't showing style change are nested within a div that has a class attribute "tech-main".
I have tried using class attribute & id attribute with the nested elements this makes no difference in browser.

I have coded with class seperatly and nested. see code snippets.

I have used ctrl F5 to clear cache.

I have tried coding an include file _tech.scss and using @import "tech" in the main scss.

I have closed all files and terminals and restarted VScode several times.

I have deleted the parent div and it's contents and then re-coded line by line thinking my html file was somehow corupted.
That didn't help. I deleted the parent div and kept the child elements, no change.

I have even tried re-nameing the child elements. i.e. class="tech" to class="stuff". Didn't work.

I don't know what elses to do to troubleshoot or remedy this problem.

Below are the three coding blocks I have tried.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////

// Tech Page
.tech-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "tech editor";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;

  .tech {
    border: 2px $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .item-lang {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////

// Tech Page
.tech-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "tech editor";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;

  &.tech {
    border: 2px $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  &.item-lang {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////
// Tech Page
.tech-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "tech editor";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tech {
    border: 2px $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.item-lang {
    text-decoration: none;
}

html block:
<div class="tech-main">
  <div class="tech">
    <h2 class="sm-heading">Languages & Frameworks I am familiar with.</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="item-lang">
        <img src="img/html5_RZ.png" alt="html5 icon" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="editor">
    <h2 class="sm-heading">Editors I have used.</h2>
    <li class="item-editor">
      <img src="img/Atom.png" width="128" height="128" alt="Atom icon" />
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I renamed the html elements. See html code.
Changed scss code. See scss code.

Now all css changes are applied as expected.

html code:

```
<div class="tech">
      <div class="tech-lang">
        <h2 class="sm-heading">Languages & Frameworks I am familiar with.</h2>
        <ul>
          <li class="item-lang">
            <img src="img/html5_RZ.png" alt="html5 icon" />
          </li>
          <li class="item-lang">
            <img src="img/css3_RZ.png" alt="Notepad++ icon" />
          </li>
          <li class="item-lang">
            <img src="img/js_RZ.png" alt="html5 icon" />
          </li>
          <li class="item-lang">
            <img src="img/php.jpg" alt="php icon" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tech-editor">
        <h2 class="sm-heading">Editors I have used.</h2>
        <li class="item-editor">
          <label>Atom</label>
          <img src="img/Atom.png" width="128" height="128" alt="Atom icon" />
        </li>
        <li class="item-editor">
          <img src="img/1Notepad++.png" width="128" height="128" alt="Notepad++ icon"/>
        </li>
        <li class="item-editor">
          <label>Sublime Text</label>
          <img src="img/sublime-icon.png" width="128" height="128" alt="Sublime Text icon"/>
        </li>
        <li class="item-editor">
          <label>VScode</label>
          <img src="img/VScode.png" width="128" height="128" alt="Sublime Text icon"/>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
```

scss code:

```
// Tech Overlay
.tech {
  border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  visibility: hidden;

  &.show {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  &-lang,
  &-editor {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  // Languages Side
  &-lang {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(darken($primary-color, 5), 0.9);
    border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    @include easeOut;

    &.show {
      // Slide in from top
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  // Editors Side
  &-editor {
    background: rgba(darken($primary-color, 5), 0.9);
    border: 2px solid $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    @include easeOut;

    &.show {
      // Slide in from bottom
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  .item-lang {
    transform: translate3d(600px, 0, 0);
    @include easeOut;

    &.show {
      // Slide in from right
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  .item-lang,
  .item-editor {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
}
// Delay each item-lang slide by 0.3s
@for $x from 1 through 4 {
  .item-lang:nth-child(#{$x}) {
    transition-delay: $x * 0.3s;
  }
}
// Delay each item-editor slide by 0.3s
@for $x from 1 through 4 {
  .item-editor:nth-child(#{$x}) {
    transition-delay: $x * 0.5s;
  }
}
```